# Custom .txt Log file using Laravel5.4

Tags: php, file, laravel-5, filesystems, laravel-5.4

Does anyone have idea or snippet to create .txt file in Laravel 5.4
I want to store data like IP, browser info, url requests etc.
want to make a custom log file for API requests I want to use it as a global function when anyone calls api function will append new request data at end of the file. thanks :)

Comment: it's unclear what you are asking about, logging functionality or how to log requests in laravel?

Comment: when anyone calls my API at that time I just want to store ip address, browser info, date time into log.txt file.

Comment: go with monolog library

Comment: thanks @hassan  for library suggestion. I have used [https://github.com/Edujugon/laravel-log](https://github.com/Edujugon/laravel-log)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own log file using `fwrite` PHP function.

### For example:

```
<?php
    $my_file = 'file.txt';
    $handle = fopen($my_file, 'a') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
    $data = 'New data line 1'."\n";
    $new_data = "\n".'New data line 2'."\n";
    fwrite($handle, $new_data);
    fwrite($handle, $data);
?>
```

Check this reference site this will helps you to understand: https://davidwalsh.name/basic-php-file-handling-create-open-read-write-append-close-delete

Comment: can I give `$my_file = 'public\logs\file.txt';` in Laravel ?

Comment: @AjarudinGunga Yes. You can store anywhere in your directory.